# Bluetooth Headphones not acting as playback device - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

I went into control panel, then hardware and sound, then clicked on Sound, and I accidentally disabled my Logitech Wireless Bluetooth headphones as a playback device, and I can't *for the life of me* figure out how to re-enable them. They are still listed and working as a mic input, but no playback output.

Please help :P

Jess

Answer (score 2):

Volume icon >> Right click >> Playback devices >> Playback tab >>
right click in the empty space you can see option to show the disabled devices